# Internationalize date format using daterangepicker.jQuery.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, daterangepicker

Hi I am working on internationalizing my site.
Currently I am using jQuery-Plugin "daterangepicker.jQuery.js"
How can I use this plugin to internationalize date format for countries other than USA?
Any immediate help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this plugin uses the same `dateFormat` method as `datepicker.jquery.js`. You can find the documentation for date formatting here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/%24.datepicker.formatDate

Comment: Can this be achieved by including Jquery, Jquery Date picker and Juqery date range picker? Can I get a sample code ? Thanks again ..

Comment: The sample code is included on the `formatDate` documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty straight forward:

```
    $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    });
```

change the yy-mm-dd to the format that you want.

Answer (score 0):

DateRangePicker (now?) uses [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for its date and time processing - including formatting of date and time.